# Unable to create process using "c:\users\hp\anaconda3\python.exe"

Tags: anaconda

C:\Users\HP\badminton_site\badminton>scrapy shell https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask

Fatal error in launcher: Unable to create process using '"c:\users\hp\anaconda3\python.exe"  "C:\Users\HP\Anaconda3\Scripts\scrapy.exe" shell https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask: The system cannot find the file specified.

Why it is showing such error in anaconda prompt and command prompt?

Answer (score 1):

Uninstall and reinstall the pip:

```
python -m pip uninstall pip

python -m pip install --upgrade pip
```

Answer (score 0):

i reinstalled the anaconda in another diretory and that worked for me